# Arduino Ethernet Board R3 with WIFI

Tags: arduino

i have been playing around with an arduino for 2 days now, so i am new to this, but i have a problem: the wifi shield wont work with the arduino ethernet R3. I got them from sparkfun:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11361
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11287

and every time i try to run this code:

```
/*

 This example  prints the Wifi shield's MAC address, and
 scans for available Wifi networks using the Wifi shield.
 Every ten seconds, it scans again. It doesn't actually
 connect to any network, so no encryption scheme is specified.

 Circuit:
 * WiFi shield attached

 created 13 July 2010
 by dlf (Metodo2 srl)
 modified 21 Junn 2012
 by Tom Igoe and Jaymes Dec
*/


#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  unsigned long start=millis();
  while (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) 
  {
    if ((millis()-start)>30000)
    {
      Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
      // don't continue:
      while(true);
    }
    delay(500);
  }

  // Print WiFi MAC address:
  printMacAddress();

  // scan for existing networks:
  Serial.println("Scanning available networks...");
  listNetworks();
}

void loop() {
  delay(10000);
  // scan for existing networks:
  Serial.println("Scanning available networks...");
  listNetworks();
}

void printMacAddress() {
  // the MAC address of your Wifi shield
  byte mac[6];                     

  // print your MAC address:
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  Serial.print("MAC: ");
  Serial.print(mac[5],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[4],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[3],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[2],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[1],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(mac[0],HEX);
}

void listNetworks() {
  // scan for nearby networks:
  Serial.println("** Scan Networks **");
  int numSsid = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  if (numSsid == -1)
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't get a wifi connection");
    while(true);
  }

  // print the list of networks seen:
  Serial.print("number of available networks:");
  Serial.println(numSsid);

  // print the network number and name for each network found:
  for (int thisNet = 0; thisNet<numSsid; thisNet++) {
    Serial.print(thisNet);
    Serial.print(") ");
    Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(thisNet));
    Serial.print("\tSignal: ");
    Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(thisNet));
    Serial.print(" dBm");
    Serial.print("\tEncryption: ");
    printEncryptionType(WiFi.encryptionType(thisNet));
  }
}

void printEncryptionType(int thisType) {
  // read the encryption type and print out the name:
  switch (thisType) {
  case ENC_TYPE_WEP:
    Serial.println("WEP");
    break;
  case ENC_TYPE_TKIP:
    Serial.println("WPA");
    break;
  case ENC_TYPE_CCMP:
    Serial.println("WPA2");
    break;
  case ENC_TYPE_NONE:
    Serial.println("None");
    break;
  case ENC_TYPE_AUTO:
    Serial.println("Auto");
    break;
  }
}
```

i get a WiFi shield not present. any ideas on how to properly connect it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products that you listed seem to be redundant.  Specifically, ~/11361 is an all-in-one arduino dev. board + Ethernet but no wireless (i.e. ethernet connection is via a cable), while ~/11287 is a WiFi shield that is used on a generic Arduino board and connects to the internet.

The problem might be that using 11287 as a shield on 11361 leads to conflicts?  I don't know, but the link http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi has the following comment:

> The WiFi library is very similar to the Ethernet library, and many of
>   the function calls are the same.

which makes me a little suspect.

Try the shield (11287) on a standard Arduino board.

Comment: Thank You!! that was the problem.